# Making a Whats Hot Section in TwentyTen (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, trending, twenty-ten-theme

Ok so, TwentyTen is a great new theme, fine.

**However**, I wish to add more functionality to it and make it like a theme having a magazine style front page (similar to [Hybrid News](http://themehybrid.com/demo/hybrid-news/)) with *mainly a **"Whats Hot"** Featured Section where I can pick up posts dynamically having the most activity on them (like checking the number of facebook likes or twitter shares or comments etc.)* I need this feature as the number of authors on my site will increase and I would need this kind of a selection mechanism to mark out the trending posts.

From what I figured out till now, I would have to add some php to my theme, and do a bit of CSS.

But, How do I go about it? Because the codex is confusing me on this one.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a job for "some PHP" and "a bit of CSS" - I'm pretty sure it's going to be much more complex. Consider looking for an existing plug-in that already does what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pekka is correct. This does require a little more ingenuity than some PHP. Try this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/) out. It's built for 2.9.2, but does work with 3.0 just fine. I'm sure the author will update it eventually since it's a popular one.